# Verify that $y(x)$ is a solution to the differentiable equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differentiable equation:

$$y'-y + \frac{1}{x} = 0 \qquad ,x>0$$

Verify that 
$$y(x) = e^x \int_x^{\infty} \frac{dt}{te^t}$$  is a solution.

I have a hard time solving this just looking at my notes and since I don't own the course book, help or pointing me in a direction to learn how to solve would be appreciated.

I know I have to plug it in and prove LHS=RHS but I can't start since I don't know how to "plug it in"

Comment: Will you undertand "substitute into" ?

Answer (score 1):

When you verify an equation using a given value, you just put it in the given equation and see if it satisfies LHS=RHS. That really is it!

In this case you'll need to be familiar with the Leibiniz rule though, for differentiation of definite integrals.

Can you pick up from here?

Comment: Oh maybe I worded this badly but I know that I have to plug it in and prove the LHS= RHS but the biggest problem is how to plug it in and then progress

Comment: @JohnDoe MrYouMath gave an apt answer, have a look

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=f(x).$$

You will obtain (in order to prevent problems at $\infty$ I will replace the limit with $a$):

$$y(x)=e^{x}\int_{x}^{a}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}.$$

We can show that this is a solution to the ODE by the following steps:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d e^{x}}{dx}\int_{x}^{a}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}+e^{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{a}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}$$
$$=e^{x}\int_{x}^{a}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}-e^{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}$$
$$=e^{x}\int_{x}^{a}\dfrac{dt}{te^{t}}-e^{x}\dfrac{1}{xe^{x}}$$
$$=y-\dfrac{1}{x}$$

$$\implies y'-y+\frac 1x=0.$$

We know that the solution is valid for any finite $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, take the limit $a\to \infty$ and show that the integral converges for $x>0$. If it converges then it is a solution to the ODE.

Comment: Ok what I don't understand is how you get the first $\frac{dy}{dx}$ expression, the rest I follow

Comment: I used the product rule $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$.

Comment: I see. What does it mean if I'm supposed to verify with numerical integration that this solution fulfills $y(\frac{1}{2} ≈ 0.9232$ Should I just integrate it to check if that's the answer I get?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integral exists. Hence you can express:
$$y(x) = e^x \int_x^{\infty} \frac{dt}{te^t}=e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)].$$
Now take derivative by using product rule:
$$y'=e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)]+e^x[-f(x)]=$$
$$e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)]+e^x[-\frac{1}{xe^x}]=e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)]-\frac1x.$$
Now substitute into the differential equation:
$$y'-y+\frac1x=\bigg[e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)]-\frac1x\bigg]-\bigg[e^x[F(\infty)-F(x)]\bigg]+\frac1x=0.$$